# Center Thumbnail Button Bootstrap

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, center

I am using the latest version of bootstrap however I cannot seem to work out how to center the button in the following piece of code. I only want it for this specific thumbnail and not globally so I cant change the css.

```
<div class="row">   
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
        <h3>Need A Price?</h3>
        <p>Fill in the Quote form and get a price within   30mins,We know you dont like waiting around</p>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Get A Quote</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to center that one button then you can take advantage of that `.btn-group` container and just target that element with your own class, that way you can define that area as `display: block` and simply align center the button like so:

**CSS**

```
.btn-centered {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML** take note of the `.btn-centered` class used on the `.btn-group` container.

```
<div class="row">   
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
        <h3>Need A Price?</h3>
        <p>Fill in the Quote form and get a price within   30mins,We know you dont like waiting around</p>
          <div class="btn-group btn-centered">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Get A Quote</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ubiwip/2

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
<p align="center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">TEST</a></p>
```